# Installation of Yosemite stalled as hdd locked

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, hdd

Today I was installing yosemite on my macbookpro 2013. 15inch. everything went smoothly till after restarting for further installation it states unable to install as hdd is locked. it then goes to disk utility. How should I continue when hdd is locked. the worse thing is i did not do any backup. please help

Regards
Herman.

Comment: Please start (in recovery mode) Terminal.app from the menubar/utilities and enter `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 1):

In Disk Utility click on the drive and click on "Enable Journaling" and it should fix the locked drive.